# Returning comparison in Python

Tags: python, boolean, return-value, primes

I have this code:

```
def isPrime(nr):
    """
    Verify if a number is prime
    nr - integer number, nr>1
    return True if nr is prime, False otherwise
    """
    div = 2 #search for divider starting from 2
    while div<nr and nr % div>0:
        div=div+1
    #if the first divider is the number itself 
    #then the number is prime
    return div>=nr
```

It's not written by me, so I'm trying to understand how the algorithm works, apparently it is using a form of divide & conquer.

What I don't understand is what the last line does:

```
return div>=nr
```

Comment: I can't see any divide and conquer.

Comment: No, there’s no divide and conquer. In addition, the algorithm highly unorthodox and inefficient.

Comment: The fact that an algorithm using division does *not* mean that it uses the *Divide and Conquer* approach...

Comment: @John Ah. Hm. I’d just skimmed the comment, seen “divide[r]” and, together with OP’s assertion, assumed that this is what the comment said. I’ll leave my (changed) comment because I still think that this code is pretty appalling. Not so much in terms of performance but in terms of readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return div>=nr
```

...is equivalent to...

```
if div >= nr:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

That is, it is not "returning a comparison" but returning *the result* of a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is just testing every number from 2 up to `nr` to test if `nr` is divisible by the number. If at any point it is (`nr % div` is equal to 0), the loop breaks. This will return False if `div < nr`. If the loop gets to `nr`, then we know there is no number between 2 and `nr` that divides the `nr` and so it is prime, returning True. The other answer explains how the return works.

Definitely not using divide & conquer.

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with an interactive environment where you can experiment with simple scripts like the one you posted.

```
$ python                           # From the command line just run 'python'.

>>> nr = 13                        # Type in some code.
>>> div = 2
>>> while div<nr and nr % div>0:
...   div=div+1
...                                # Press 'Enter' here to end the indentation.
>>> div                            # Type a variable to see what it equals.
13
>>> nr                             # Again.
13
>>> div>=nr                        # Ahhh, the answer to your question.
True
>>>
```